# How to implement multicast/broadcast function in omnet++ inet switch model?

Tags: simulation, omnet++, multicast, inet, switching

I made a network where 5 `StandardHost` are connecting to a `Switch`. One of the `StandardHost` acts as the source (`UdpBasicApp`) while the other four act as the sink (`UdpSinkApp`).
I want to constantly multicast/broadcast packets from the source to the sinks. For example, multicast to only two sinks out of four. How can I do that? I've tried to manually write the `macTable.forwardingTable` (through `**.switch.macTable.forwardingTableFile`) but found no success.